# Platform ready event doesn't fire inside app initializer with Ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an Ionic3 application that has several dependencies to third party services and Cordova plugins.

What I tried to do is to use `APP_INITIALIZER` to make sure I do all initialization before application starts.

To avoid race condition and make sure plugins are loaded at the moment `APP_INITIALIZER` starts I wanted to do

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Initialization here
});
```

But `ready` event never fires. If I remove `ready` block, this will work sometimes (even most of times) but will still fail at some moments